# How can I "dequantize" macro blocks in a highly compressed image using OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, compression, image-compression

Given a highly compressed image (non-specific format) there are various sized and shaped blocks of the image in which all pixels have exactly the same value.

For example:

[image: Highly compressed image with "macro blocking"]

My goal is to "intelligently" smooth these blocks into gradients producing a smoother more organic looking image. I've seen in-painting techniques (such as heat diffusion) that might be applicable though I'm not entirely sure how to adapt them to my purpose. I'm currently writing my own function to perform this action (details below). Is there is already a C++ function in OpenCV (or elsewhere) that can perform this process? If not, is there a different method than the one I am using that might produce better/faster results?

[Note: All of my images are converted to floating point before processing.]

My current idea involves testing whether a pixel is identical to any of it's neighbors. If so I begin a search starting from the pixel location and working outward until a non-identical neighbor is found. This unfortunately requires that I use the entire image rather than a sliding kernel. I won't include the code of the search here because it is long and repetitive. But it essentially involves testing a column to the left, a row above, a column to the right, and a row below the current pixel and expanding them as I work outward. Like this:

```
  13 14 15 16 17
  12  3  4  5 18
  11  2  x  6 19
  10  1  7  8 20
  9  22 23 24 21
```

Once a target is acquired, additional consideration is taken for targets that may be in a larger search range but have a smaller euclidean distance.

If the color difference is within an acceptable range, I then calculate the euclidean distance of the nearest non-identical neighbor and calculate a pixel value based on the euclidean distance and the color difference between the two non-identical pixels. I also use a user set sigma value to affect the falloff of the gradient.

```
output_value = current_pixel_value - ((current_pixel_value-test_pixel_value)/(euclidean_distance*sigma));
```

This method works "ok" but it is slow in images that have huge macro blocks and the output still has a "banded" look to it. (See "white" sections of walls, floors, etc).

Result:
[image: "Dequantized" result image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper [Advanced Video Debanding](http://www.mee.tcd.ie/~sigmedia/pmwiki/uploads/Main.Publications/BaughKP14.pdf) by Gary Baugh et al. does what you do for over-compressed video. The underlying algorithm should also be applicable to still image. Maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is excellent. It uses a very similar approach to the one I am using but also introduces the concept of dithering the gradients after generation in order to give a more natural look and prevent the gradient from being re-quantized by additional write functions. I will post additional results once I have implemented the changes.